# Problem in executing a shell script present on host using docker exec

Tags: bash, docker, amazon-emr

I'm trying to execute a script on the master node of AWS EMR cluster. The intention is to create a new conda env and link it to jupyter. I'm following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-install-kernels-libs.html) doc from AWS. Problem is, whatever be the content of the script, I'm getting the same error: `bash: /home/hadoop/scripts/bootstrap.sh: No such file or directory` while executing `sudo docker exec jupyterhub bash /home/hadoop/scripts/bootstrap.sh`. I've made sure the sh file is in the correct location.

But if I copy the `bootstrap.sh` file inside the container, and then run the same docker exec cmd, it's working fine. What am I missing here? I've tried with a simple script with the following entries, but it throws the same error:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello"
```

The doc clearly says:

> Kernels are installed within the Docker container. The easiest way to
>   accomplish this is to create a bash script with installation commands,
>   save it to the master node, and then use the **sudo docker exec
>   jupyterhub script_name** command to run the script within the jupyterhub
>   container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker exec` command runs a command within the container's namespaces. One of those namespaces is the filesystem. So unless the command is part of the image, written into the container directly, or you have mounted a host volume to map a host directory into the container, you won't be able to execute it. A host volume could look like:

```
docker run -v /host/scripts:/container/scripts -n your_container $your_image
docker exec -it your_container /container/scripts/test.sh
```

That host volume could be the same path on both the host and the container.

If it is a shell script, you could use I/O redirection, e.g.:

```
docker exec -i $container_id /bin/bash <local_script.sh
```

but be aware that you cannot do interactive stuff this way since the script content has replaced your terminal as stdin. This works because the shell inside the container is just processing commands from stdin.

Other than those scenarios, I don't know what to tell you other than the documentation from AWS appears to be wrong.